# android - callback function for handling crashes

Tags: android

I need to handle crashes in android application,Is there any callback function or overridden method in activity class which will be called when the app crashes?
Guide me in solving this...

Answer (score 6):

You can set an uncaught exception handler which will be called every time. Like this

```
     final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
            // do your magic
            defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, throwable);
        }
    });
```

You should probably subclass the Application class and run this code as the first thing in the OnCreate method. Getting the default handler and passing the exception along is to ensure proper handling after you are done performing magic.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: :exactly what i need is,a function call when app crashes..i.e whenever app crashes by default  the function has to be called..

Comment: The uncaughtException method above will get called every time your app crashes.